# Any impact of restart OWSTIMER every hour?

Tags: sharepoint

I found OWSTIMER consume a lot of memory during create personal sites. (I have to pre-create personal sites for many users)

After googling I found some suggestion to restart OWSTIMER but it’ll grow up again after create several personal sites. So I have to restart OWSTIMER every hour.

Did you know any impact of restart OWSTIMER every hour?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

OWSTIMER is notorious for leaks and a general pain in the @$$ sometimes.

The only impact should be that timed job will not be started during the brief (5-10 second) outage as the service restarts.

More information is available from Ben Curry at http://www.mindsharpblogs.com/ben/archive/2007/09/25/2965.aspx